# Fixed navbar on scroll depending on its height in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im trying to make a fixed top navbar that is under header, on scroll. The thing is that in my project I don't know how high my navbar will be so I can't hard code it. I made this:

```
 const [isFixed, setIsFixed] = useState(false);
  const categoriesRef = useRef(null);

  const categoriesFixed = () => {
    if (window.pageYOffset > categoriesRef.current.offsetTop) setIsFixed(true);
    else setIsFixed(false);
  };

useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', categoriesFixed);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', categoriesFixed);
    };
  }, []);

return (
    <div className="categories py-4">
      <div className="container-fluid">
        <nav ref={categoriesRef} className={`categories-nav border ${isFixed && 'fixed-categories'}`}>
          <div className="categories-container">
         
          </div>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
```

This works when scrolling down, but when scrolling up the navbar is fixed so my function doesnt get it's offSetTop from categoriesRef.current.offsetTop and stops being fixed only when I scroll just to the top of window. Is there a way to do it properly?

Comment: If "IE" doesn't have to be supported you can check css `position: sticky` it is much more easier to use. Otherwise you shouldn't use the nav "offsettop" but the computed height of the navbar (with getBoundingRect from the header). If you still want to use offsetTop, you still can save it in the state and using the saved value instead.

Comment: You could add some extra top offset to the `navbar`'s top offset: `if (window.pageYOffset > categoriesRef.current.offsetTop + 50) setIsFixed(true)`;